# How to go about making educational videos of handwritten instructions on a digital pad, where the hands won't be included in the videos?

Tags: video, video-editor, video-recording, youtube

How do we use a digital board/pad to make pre-recorded (not live) YouTube videos of the handwritten instructions, so that hand(s) wouldn't be visible in the videos, but you'll actually use your hand (and not the computer mouse) to write on the board? So basically, to make these videos, you'll write on a digital pad/board connected to your computer, so the computer screen would contain just what you're writing minus your hand, and the video of those writings can be saved afterwards? The best descripotion is some Khan Academy videos: e.g.

is where you see just what you need, minus the hands, or the instructor himself.

If possible, how exactly do we do it? One idea is described here -

, but I'd still love to see if there're other simpler ideas out there, possibly not involving buying a very expensive digital board. Some digital board are less than 100€, but some are 1000€ (!).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be to get a graphic tablet (like a Wacom tablet or a cheaper alternative) and record the screen as you write on a drawing program such as gimp, illustrator, Photoshop, paint.net, etc. with a recording program such as OBS. You can set up custom pens that use the speed, angle, pressure, etc. of your drawing to imitate the look of a pen and to create a similar effect to one of these videos.

Comment: The graphics pad that I first got was 25 USD and it is an XP Pen Star something

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'll check out the Wacom tablet etc. Do you possibly have an Amazon link or other such links so I can check out the features in detail? TIA!

I've Streammab OBS recently installed in my laptop, I guess that'll help me record the screen when I write?

Comment: Wacom CTL4100 Intuos Graphics Drawing Tablet with 3 Bonus Software included, 7.9"x 6.3", Black https://www.amazon.com/dp/B079HL9YSF/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_d-o5DbNJGE1MW - $50

Comment: XP-PEN Deco 01 V2 Graphics Tablet 10x6.25 Inch Drawing Pen Tablet 8192 Levels Pressure Battery-Free Pen with Tilt Function Android Supported and 8 Shortcut Keys https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07VKB37HZ/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_8.o5DbGPEM0W7 this one is much bigger and a little cheaper

Comment: XP-Pen G430S OSU Tablet Ultrathin Graphic Tablet 4 x 3 inch Digital Tablet Drawing Pen Tablet for OSU! (8192 Levels Pressure) https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01BA6XQI0/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_4ap5Db6WMFQ1V this is very cheap

Comment: These are all very cheap graphics tablets

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, drawing-pads are usually used. However, you can draw on paper in a light-tent and imitate the motion of pens and brushes over the paper in post. This will be a more difficult option though as it takes much more time in post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what kind of drawing pads do you mean? Is it electronid or digital? What I don't want to do is to use a camera to videotape myself writing down the instructions on the pad. Hence I want some kind of digital pad that can be connected to the computer and allow me to make me a video of me writing on the board, but the video must not show myself, or my hand; it'd just show the writings on the board, and the board itself of course!

Comment: Believe it or not, but these pads do in fact exist :D
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07VRQM5LY/ref=sspa_dk_detail_3?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B07VRQM5LY&pd_rd_w=0eShL&pf_rd_p=45a72588-80f7-4414-9851-786f6c16d42b&pd_rd_wg=oninb&pf_rd_r=TBMTNHGAQ7WCA4J5MS8J&pd_rd_r=23822837-e764-424a-a23e-05b7a02dc5bc&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFNQTUxRlNNQkZZU1kmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTA2MjA3MTExUUFQWExTQ09GUzVEJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA4OTI0MzgzOFVIVTUwTTNWSkdGJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfZGV0YWlsJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==

Comment: You might want to keep in mind that you will need proper screen-recording too. If that is not something you're an expert at, I would recommend using something like Fraps or Camtasia even, but using Open Broadcast or ffmpeg would be the "proper" way. Both work tho.